# JavaScript framework for online cinema

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I'm trying to find some **front-end** framework for multimedia portal or simply online cinema for using in my Single Page application.

There are many different universal solutions which are suitable for wide range of tasks, but do you know something more thematic, something specialized?

Thank you very much for your help!

P.S. I'm interested in something for such layout and functionality:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one Portal you can look into on https://codecanyon.net/item/ticket-bazzar-online-ticket-booking/18316164?s_rank=30 that has been using Angular JS Framework